# porting .net => ruby, can I respond to urls ending in .aspx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My .net application has a url that ends with .aspx like:

```
www.example.com/users/find.aspx?userid=234234
```

I don't want to re-write the url, I want to keep it as is.

Is it possible for a Rails 3 application (nginx, passenger) to respond to this request using a customized route?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you need to update your routes file (config/routes.rb).

See:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just add a route to config/routes.rb. In Rails 3 that would like:

match 'users/find.aspx' => 'users#find'